# Roblox not letting me vote game

Tags: roblox

hello I made a game and I uploaded it in my roblox group and whenever someone tries to vote it.It gives an error that you do not have permision i anyone has faced this problem please reply me for solution.I have looked on the internet and have not found any solutions

Comment: choco cremo gamer, StackOverflow is not the place for questions like this.
If you're having issues on the Roblox website, please send a message to Roblox's customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, You may have already solved this yourself, and again, StackOverflow is NOT the place for questions like that. But the problem is the game is Private.